# PostgreSQL PHP last id values from different tables to another table

Tags: php, database, postgresql

Im trying to create a table which only will have the serial and 9 int foreign keys.

Is there a way to insert the last id from other tables to this table? 
i been trying with RETURNING, nextval()-1, currval(),ordering results by timestamp but nothing seems to work, i just cant get the ids values from the other tables inserted into the table.
even tried this simple set of queries for each table to update one by one of the table columns

```
  $lst="SELECT id from table1 ORDER BY timestamp DESC limit 1";
  $lst_res=pg_query($conn,$lst);
$sql_eq_bat_up="UPDATE table9 set table1_id='$lst_res[id]'";
  $do_up_tbl1=pg_query($conn,$sql_eq_bat_up);
```

i been doing some research but had no luck, im using postgreSQL 9.5 and php for this, i hope you can help me thanks.

Comment: Your PHP snippet isn't correct. After `pg_query()` you need to call `pg_fetch_assoc($query_result)` to get the row.

Comment: Nextval() - 1 will increment your sequence! Currval of a sequence can do the job, why it doesn't work?

Comment: You were right my code was wrong it needed another pg_query and a pg_fetch_assoc. THANKS.